# DataBinding problems with custom UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a strange issue when using DataBinding on a custom UserControl. 
My UserControl "UserControl1" has a dependency property LabelText which sets the content of a label within my UserControl1. Furthermore, it has a button that binds the command "MyCommand". This command just shows a message box and is implemented in UserControl1ViewModel.

When I using UserControl1 in my MainWindow with also has its view model (MainWindowViewModel), I would like to set the UserControl's LabelText property in the MainWindow.xaml using a Binding to LabelTextFromMainWindow, but when I do it I have a problem that it uses the wrong DataContext unless you specify it explicitly.

This my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm = new MainWindowViewModel();

        vm.LabelTextFromMainWindow = "Hallo";
    }
}

class MainWindowViewModel : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    private string myLabel;

    public string LabelTextFromMainWindow
    {
        get { return myLabel; }
        set
        {
            myLabel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyLabel");
        }
    }
}

/////////

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="224" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Content="Button" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,99,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
        <Label Margin="30,99,0,0" Name="label1" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="101" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private UserControl1ViewModel vm;

    private static UserControl1 instance;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        instance = this;

        DataContext = vm = new UserControl1ViewModel();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""), OnValidateValueProperty);

    private static bool OnValidateValueProperty(object source)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            instance.label1.Content = source;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class UserControl1ViewModel
{
    private DelegateCommand myCommand;

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (myCommand == null)
                myCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action<object>(MyExecute),
                    new Predicate<object>(MyCanExecute));
            return myCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool MyCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void MyExecute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My mainwindow logs as followed:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 LabelText="{Binding
                                Path=DataContext.LabelTextFromMainWindow,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"  
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Margin="114,36,0,0"
                         x:Name="userControl11"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="236" Width="292" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I exspected the following to work correctly.

```
LabelText="{Binding Path=LabelTextFromMainWindow}"
```

However, I have to write this one.

```
LabelText="{Binding Path=DataContext.LabelTextFromMainWindow,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                       AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

What do I have to do in order get the simple Binding to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default control `inherits DataContext from its parent` unless you set it `explicitly`.
In your case, you explicitly set the DataContext of your UserControl as

```
DataContext = vm = new UserControl1ViewModel();
```

which makes all the bindings on your UserControl to look for bindings in class `UserControl1ViewModel` instead in `MainWindowViewModel`.

That's why you have to use `RelativeSource` to get Window's DataContext i.e. `you explicitly asked binding to be found in window's DataContext` instead in its own DataContext and i see no issue in using RelativeSource.

But, if you want to work like simple binding without RelativeSource, first of all `you need to get rid of explicitly setting DataContext` and move all commands and properties in `MainWindowsViewModel` so that your UserControl inherits its DataContext from MainWindow.

OR

You can give name to your window and bind using `ElementName` -

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainWindow"> <--- HERE
<Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 LabelText="{Binding
                                       Path=DataContext.LabelTextFromMainWindow, 
                                       ElementName=MainWindow}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks to your explaination, I found a better solution myself. If my UserControl1 has no DataContext, but the first child item (in this case a Grid with name "DataContextHolder") I can get what I am looking for.

<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1">
 <Grid x:name="DataContextHolder">
 </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
 public UserControl1()
 {
  DataContextHolder.DataContext = new UserControl1ViewModel();
 }
}

Comment: Yeah that's a sort of hack but good enough for your problem statement.